# c program calculating grade point average

Tags: arrays, function

Write a simple c program that calculates the grade point average of students. It should prompt a user to enter the student marks, and then show the letter grades for the marks. it should output the average of the grade points

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the prompting and output yourself, but here's a way to figure out the average:

```
int avg_gpa = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < num_students; i++) {
    avg_gpa += student[i].gpa;
}
avg_gpa = avg_gpa / num_students;
```